# How to use the 'contents' field of the jQuery ajax call to handle the response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a problem with an ajax request to a site.

It returns as a response a json object and I cannot handle it with a success:function(data)  like usual.
I get a

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

error on *chrome*, and

> SyntaxError: invalid label  {"response":{

on *firefox*...

the response is :

```
{"response":{
  "header": {
    "found": 6,
    "query": "something"
  },
  "results": [
    { ... }
  ]
}
```

I thought of using the **contents** field of the ajax() function to wrap the response somehow, but there is no example to see how it's used.
Any other ideas to handle the request?

this is the call I make:

```
$.ajax({
     url:'http://somesite.com/search/query',
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     data: { q: 'something' },
     success:function(json){
         // debugger;
         alert("Success");
     },
     error:function(err, data){
         alert("Error");
     },
});
```

From the jQuery website 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**contents**
Type: PlainObject
An object of string/regular-expression pairs that determine how jQuery will parse the response, given its content type. (version added: 1.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting an error is because it's not valid JSONP, but just regular JSON missing the callback, and there's nothing you can do about that, other than getting the content on the serverside or having the external service change their API, as JSONP is the only datatype supported for cross domain requests, unless CORS is enabled.

Comment: But I see the request response having everything I need inside. There is no other way to 'capture' this response object? Is there a way to setup a 'listener' to capture this response maybe?

Comment: Nope, there's no way to get the data, even if you can see it in the console. If it's not valid JSONP, it won't work, and you can't change the datatype if it's cross domain. Not all services support JSONP, you'll need to read the documentation for the API, and if it only supports JSON, you'll need to get the data on your server, and use an ajax call to your own server to get the data, or you could use a service like YQL, if you're willing to take a performance hit.

Comment: It's just a personal project at the moment, so I guess I can try YQL. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo Query Language is another option for you.

Links:

http://yuiblog.com/sandbox/yui/3.2.0pr1/examples/io/io-xdr.html

http://staff.washington.edu/tabrooks/343INFO/yqlJSON.htm